# What do we really mean by the word "light"?

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, terminology

Does the term "light" refer to any electromagnetic wave or just the visible spectrum?

Answer (score 3):

One of the tags you used indicates the answer. What one meant by "light" historically corresponds to the visible part of the full spectrum of electromagnetic waves. However, qualitatively, visible or not, all electromagnetic waves share the same properties except for their frequency. Thus, one often refers to any of the electromagnetic waves with the word "light"--and it is only fair. If the context requires more specification, one uses words such as "visible light" or "infrared light" or "UV light" to be clearer.